# Lftp, mirror и установка прав

Tags: ftp, chmod, linux

Всем привет.

На debian машине используется lftp скрипт, который с помощью команды mirror получает новые файлы с удалённого сервера:

```
open remote-site.govmirror -P 5 -v -n --only-newer --use-cache /pub/dir /mydirexit
```

Как установить права на новые файлы? Файлов в /mydir очень много и chmor -R не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

зачем у вас дублируются опции?

> -n, --only-newer    download only newer files (-c won't work)

вообще поумолчанию оно должно копировать permissons. попробуйте --no-umask, эта команда должна отменять "наложение" umask в целевой системе.

зыж по мне так rsync более удобная тула...

Comment: необходимо именно задать свои права, при этом не совпадающие с правами директории. То есть указать произвольный chmod и chown для скопированного файла. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: нет, так не получится, причем ни в одной системе так не получится :) только отдельными командами.